# how can I emulate iMac Retina 5K through chrome dev tools and target through CSS?

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools, screen-resolution

I've been working on a clients website and they have recently bought an iMac retina 5k. Since they have bought this the text on the website has shrunk so that its hardly readable. My main question is how can I emulate this in Chrome dev tools. I understand that the screen dimensions are 5120px by 2880px. What is the dpr for these devices and how can I target them using CSS?

Comment: This is a similar question too.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11012724/change-font-size-depending-on-resolution.       Not to be mean but I found it with my first search with Google.    Good luck with your project

Comment: How does that answer my question?

Comment: Are you using JavaScript to change the dppx ratio? AKAIK it can't be done with meta viewport commands alone. By default, the browsers use a reasonably sane dppx, so that you shouldn't have to worry about these things.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the SVG format, @media queries CSS and CSS @font-face property could be helpful. I found this for you:
[enter link description here](http://justcreative.com/2016/01/14/4k-and-retina-5k-website-design/)